# Moving 'Sent' Transaction from Default Account

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

I would like to move a sent transaction from the default account to another account held on the same wallet.

I am using version 0.16 so I still have the depreciated accounts functionality.

I'm not exactly sure how to do this or if it is even possible. I was thinking the 'move' or 'setaccount' commands would do it but I'm not sure how to compile the command.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: move a sent transaction?

Comment: Yes, move sent transaction to another account.

Comment: can you explain what you're trying to achieve, that doesn't really make sense to me. Do you mean reassigning account names: https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.3/rpc/wallet/setaccount/

Comment: Is it possible to add a comment to a sent transaction after it has been sent?

Comment: With the bitcoin core wallet, I don't think so.